# IOS perform segue from tab bar item

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a Tab bar controller with 2 items. The first item is a VC which contains a table view. Clicking on a cell, performs a segue to some other view controller (not an item on the tab bar controller).

The problem is that it removes the tab bar when segue completes.
How can I just replace the item 1 with other VC and still keep the tab bar in the bottom?

[image: My Storyboard]

Comment: Can you show you storyboard?

Comment: You need to embed your Item1 VC to `Navigationcontroller`, try once after embeded with navigationController.

Comment: Yes, it did the work. Can you tell why? How can I do it without nav controller? Thanks btw!

Comment: Check my answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed your `Item1VC` to `NavigationController` so that when you push from `ItemVC`to `MoviesViewController` it will not remove the tabbar, if you doesn't embed the `NavigationController` then it will push from the main `ViewController`in your case it is `TabbarController` so that you are not able to see the tabbar.

Comment: Still, why it pushes the TabBarController, although the segue is from the item 1 VC ? The case where I am not using nav controller.

Comment: Told you that, If you doesn't embed the NavigationController then it will push from the main ViewController in your case it is TabbarController so that you are not able to see the tabbar.

Comment: Now Got it  :)  ?

Comment: Yes I have already understand. Yet, my question is why is that the case? why it pushes from the tabBarController? The segue itself is from item 1 VC and not from the tabBarController

Comment: I don't understand how to explain you but without `NavigationController` it will always push from the main screen of app.